# diagonal matrix and unbiaseness

Tags: regression, self-study

Let the model be linear $Y=X\beta+e$ with $m$ covariates in X and error be i.i.d Gaussian. I noticed that if there are some collinearity in X then, $X'X$ is not diagonal. Then the estimation of the parameter is biased, $\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$. Is that really true that estimations are biased in the presence of collinearity in variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ and $E(\varepsilon) = 0$ then (as Brian mentioned) $E(\hat \beta) = \beta$. That happens no matter what $X$ is (provided it is known and fixed), although we are assuming that $X$ is full rank when we use the existence of $(X^T X)^{-1}$.

What happens when $X^T X$ is diagonal is that each $\hat \beta_i$ is independent. Without loss of generality let's assume that $X^T X = I_p$, so that $X$ is orthonormal. Let's also assume $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2 I_n)$ so that these results are exact rather than asymptotic. We can show from this that $\hat \beta \sim \mathcal N(\beta, (X^T X)^{-1}\sigma^2)$ so if $X^T X = I$ then $\forall i \neq j$ $Cov(\hat \beta_i, \hat \beta_j) = 0$ $\implies$ $\hat \beta_i \perp \hat \beta_j$ (since they're jointly normal).

So, in conclusion, when our predictors are correlated (and consequently $X^T X$ is not diagonal) we still have unbiasedness, but it is no longer the case that $\hat \beta_i \perp \hat \beta_j$. This means that the addition or deletion of one predictor may affect the estimated effects of the other predictors.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=X\beta$, then what is $E[\hat{\beta}]$?  It's pretty easy to show that $E[\hat{\beta}]=\beta$.